# Is there a way to check if a type is undefined or another specific value to determine function return type?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to do something like the below? The goal is for `bar()` to return a string, but `bar(10)` to return a number.

```
function bar<T>(baz?: T): (T extends typeof undefined ? string : number)  {
    if (baz === undefined) {
        return '42'
    }
    return 42
}
```

Comment: The compiler will not be able to verify that `"42"` or `42` is assignable to a generic conditional type like `T extends undefined ? string : number`; this is a missing feature described at [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).  For something simple like this with just two possible output types you might want to just write an overloaded function as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w6pgRm).  Does that fully address your question?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That's perfect @jcalz thanks! I didn't know that type of function overload was possible, so very helpful for future tasks :)  You should copy/paste this as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write a function in TypeScript where the return type depends on the types of the arguments, then you will either need to make it a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function with a call signature that expresses things in terms of one or more type parameters, or an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) with multiple call signatures.  Which one you use is a matter of what your use cases are.

---

Your example shows an approach that is trying to use generics, so let's look at that first.  The output should be `string` if the argument is missing or undefined, or `number` if the argument is present and defined.  It's actually quite annoying to write a generic call signature for that.  There's no simple built-in mapping between those inputs and outputs.  You could write something like this:

```
declare function bar<T extends [baz?: unknown]>(...[baz]: T):
  T extends [undefined?] ? string : number;
```

where you've got `T` corresponding to the [generic tuple type of the rest parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#generic-rest-parameters), and where the return type is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  So when someone calls `bar()`, then `T` is inferred as the empty tuple `[]`.  And if someone calls `bar(true)`, then `T` is inferred as the one-tuple `[boolean]` (or maybe `[true]`).  And then if `T` is assignable to `[undefined?]` (meaning a tuple of length zero, or a tuple of length one containing `undefined`), then a `string` comes out, otherwise it's a number.

(Do note that [the `undefined` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined) exists and you don't need to write `typeof undefined`.)

That works well enough for callers:

```
const x = bar(); // const x: string;
console.log(x.repeat(2)); // "4242"
const y = bar(true); // const y: number;
console.log(y.toFixed(2)); // "42.00"
```

But when you implement it you'll get warnings because generic conditional types are beyond the compiler's ability to reason about:

```
function bar<T extends [baz?: unknown]>(...[baz]: T):
  T extends [undefined?] ? string : number {
  if (baz === undefined) {
    return '42'; // error! 
    // 'string' is not assignable to 'T extends [undefined?] ? string : number'.
  }
  return 42 // error! 
  // 'number' is not assignable to 'T extends [undefined?] ? string : number'.
}
```

That's essentially a missing feature of TypeScript described at [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).  For now you'd have to work around that by using something like a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to silence the errors.  It's not any more type safe (it won't catch if you mix up `return 42` with `return '42'`), but it's at least less noisy:

```
function bar<T extends [baz?: unknown]>(...[baz]: T):
  T extends [undefined?] ? string : number {
  if (baz === undefined) {
    return '42' as T extends [undefined?] ? string : number // okay
  }
  return 42 as T extends [undefined?] ? string : number // okay
}
```

But yuck, that's not ergonomic at all.  The call signature is complex and confusing, and the implementation needs assertions or the like.  It's ugly.

---

On the other hand, you can write it as an overloaded function with one call signature for each call type you'd like to support, in the order you'd like it to be resolved.  And then after all your call signatures you'd implement the function with a somewhat looser call signature.  Here are the call signatures:

```
// call signatures
function bar(baz?: undefined): string;
function bar(baz: unknown): number;
```

Those are already a lot nicer than the weird generic conditional rest tuple craziness above.  Then you implement it using a wide input and output type that "covers" all call signatures:

```
// implementation
function bar(baz?: unknown): string | number {
  if (baz === undefined) {
    return '42'
  }
  return 42
}
```

There are no errors in the implementation here.  Note that isn't because the compiler is any smarter about type checking here.  If you mix up `return 42` and `return '42'` it will still not catch the mistake.  But overload bodies are checked more loosely compared to generic conditional return types, so it's at least more ergonomic to write.

And it also works well from the caller's side:

```
const x = bar();
console.log(x.repeat(2)); // "4242"
const y = bar(true);
console.log(y.toFixed(2)); // "42.00"
```

Overloads definitely have their drawbacks, but in this case it's much less ugly to do so.  And if you just want to support concrete calls to `bar`, it should work well enough.

---

So in this case you probably want to use an overloaded function, at least with the information given in the question.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgOITAQBOAlvHvoUUgGYCuw8ALvQHtgSAEYhaAHgAqSCAA9e1ACZQkAbTFYA-AC4k3ANbABAd2ABdAHwAKAHT2NILOb1SAlDtZskM+YuAq6txKEOz0NEpa5khaSFC8DMAA5kh6wJxgInTM3kT07EjWmkgAvGX6AaHhEEpuOblEtBC8nLTCAOQALABM7QDcSAD0g7K0tAK0AIRIXrnDSO3xiUntSPSqxrxIIFBQ9EmgIhjIvAILvgrKqmrBVRFRMXEJ4SlpGVm07bazRAC+P0gmi02kgekMRnRxlMZg15u10pk6Kt1sQBFsdnsDiAjiczu0Lv5AjdKmF7tFYksXqliO8kd9vP8WN54EJ4kg5KVROJrG4+rMWcAoAJjrYMAIktY5LYmjAICBeNZum5eeCkAAiHo9NX81lbACenLEtGsCU4EF5OsFwogovF1j1tlOADF6HIaorlQN5hrurYAAx+7V-FisEjQOCIJBUGgMeDdZizLg8fhCLmSAlXdSaXQVIymCw2ey2RzOVweAEZgLXW6kmoPCnPZLUhEferefKFYplEoVEK12pt3JA1odHqrHY+WSXKtBEnVSLkp7LZu02iqgQGEB6gH-BrDkFgieVok1+f1pdUt6ItfzDdb2aMy1sjk9o08vnM1nW20SqUyuUKkqKrepq3RBmwApsgar7cqa5ofhBX4imKEoOs6rrukBXojD6-qBqwjJEGGZCRgA8gAbnQYogIEBDeLM8zoBgGBxPsoDAtAibcHwgjCG+2Z6KeEQeBeyQIUQSY8am-FOIJwB5mYIktnQfIMSM9BgDAxyQMAvDyrxXHJrxaZFE4OaGMYil6JSTYAD40teg55AUpk4N2vZ3DUdR0Q0gLNCOCxjjuAL7sIPQPkyiGClsL4mRan5Wshdp-hAsryh6wE4aB4FEJB+qGrBtBmvFUVCklqGOgILpukoGXYeqPR4dqBH4L8QA)

Answer (score 1):

That's a use case of Function Overloads: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads

```js
function bar(): string;
function bar(baz: number): number;
function bar(baz?: number): string | number {
    if (baz === undefined) {
        return '42'
    }
    return 42
}

const a = bar(); // string
const b = bar(10); // number
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=28&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAIwIYCcAUBKAXIgZynRjAHMBuAKFElgRQ0zQC98wQBbZAU3T0QdufarWjwkaLKwD87Lr374iJcogA%20ghX0QBvKokOIYwRM1QtEAXhuJwAEx7BSPe9j0GjX9Dygh0SADkACwATIGehgC%20kYg%20fgGIYVQxVBAIRIio1oxY2BSIAPSFhMSkZGkZUCg5UpgAjAAM7sVawuhAA)